# In Super 8, why did the monster take prisoners?

Tags: super-8

In Super 8, the monster took a number of humans prisoner.  Why?  Why take them back to its lair and store them, unconscious?

It is seen taking one human prisoner down, and doing *something* with them, and it was in the process of taking Alice down as well before it was interrupted.  What was it doing with them?

It seemed that it most likely killed some of the prisoners, in particular the sheriff and the other woman who tried to escape, but why keep them alive until then (especially since the sheriff was likely the very first human captured)?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie yet.  Are there monster's in it?

Comment: @Lars "monster" is a relative term.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I thought it was eating the people -- didn't it have a limb that was detached and it was gnawing on? If that's true, it would be storing them alive to preserve freshness. (Or possibly flavor.) When it was held by the army, I think that it ate meat -- that's what the one guy who had the connection was bringing when he was grabbed.

The implication was that it had assumed

> that the people were all hostile after its experience with the military. Something about the kids convinced it not to eat them -- perhaps because of some psychic connection. Part of the point of the movie was that the motives of the alien were hard to understand.

Comment: I just watched this - one of the kids did mention that the creature appeared to be eating people.